# Acessing the 'options' menu from a fragment? Android

Tags: java, android

I currently have an app which has 4 pages, these pages are being added using fragments by a pageViewer, so that I can swipe between them.

What I want, is to be able to access the 'options' menu (the one which has a 'settings' item in it by default) from each page, so that I can perform commands specifically for one page, such as a 'refresh' item, which refreshes the data in the current page.

Could anyone point me in the right direction? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each `Fragment` can declare its own menu, which will be automatically merged with the current activity's menu.

```
class YourPage extends Fragment
{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Signal that this fragment has proper actions
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) 
    {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

        // The menu will be added to the action bar
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_page_menu, menu);      
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.action_refresh:
            {
                // Handle the action...

                return true;
            }


            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }       
    }   
}
```

Here's a complete [example](https://hostr.co/eGGd5QkG1HYH) that I made, and also a relevant [tutorial](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/adding-action-items-from-within-fragments/).

Comment: Actually, just one thing. The items are now appearing twice in the options menu (2xRefresh item, 2xSettings item) HOw ould I make it only show one of each?

Comment: The problem is that the fragments near the visible one is loaded as well. Try adding menu in fragment only when getUserVisibleHint() is true.

Comment: Ah I found out why. In my OnCreateOptioneMenu() I had this code: inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);, which meant that the menu was being added here also :P Thanks for all the help!