# FragmentActivity Action Bar Options Menu

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-fragmentactivity, android-menu

I'm trying to add ActionBar buttons to a FragmentActivity and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.
When running the app all I see is the default menu button on the ActionBar and not my button..

The FragmentActivity :

```
   @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.animalsmenu,menu);
    return true;
}
```

The xml file:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/dogs"
    android:title="Dogs"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    app:showAsAction="always">
</item>
```

Comment: Take a look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25700575/acessing-the-options-menu-from-a-fragment-android/25700901#25700901

Comment: @XDnl : The question (according to the OP) shows code from a `FragmentActivity`, not a `Fragment`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `FragmentActivity` class extends (derives from) the `Activity` class. The documentation for the `Activity` [onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu)) method states the following...

> The default implementation populates the menu with standard system menu items. These are placed in the CATEGORY_SYSTEM group so that they will be correctly ordered with application-defined menu items. **Deriving classes should always call through to the base implementation.**

In other words, change your code to...

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.animalsmenu, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    return true;
}
```

This will inflate your menu item into the `Menu` passed in to your overridden method and then you pass it to the parent (`super`) version of the method.

Comment: @james : Are you directly extending `FragmentActivity` or do you have a base class of your own which extends `FragmentActivity` and then you're extending that?

Comment: I'm directly extending FragmentActivity

Comment: @james : Are you building using the 'native' libraries or the support libraries, e.g., android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity?

Comment: This class is using the android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity , Sorry i forgot to mention that.

Comment: @james : OK, so what is your `minSdkVersion` in your AndroidManifest? If you're using support libraries there's a possibility you might have a mismatch of classes.

Comment: minSdkVersion is 14. p.s Thank you very much for trying to help

Comment: @james : Without seeing more code it's difficult to advise completely but it seems like you can get rid of the support libraries altogether. The `ActionBar` and `Fragments` were introduced in API 11. If you're building for API 14 onwards the standard runtime implementation of the `Activity` class allows using the `ActionBar` and also `Fragments`. Try changing your `FragmentActivity` to just an `Activity` and any 'support` related classes and methods to the native ones.

Comment: The problem is that i'm using a ViewPager wich requires a FragmentActivity to it's FragmentManager

Comment: @james : Hmmm, I hadn't realised the `ViewPager` class is only available in the v4 support library. The documentation for `FragmentActivity` does suggest using `ActionBarActivity` instead - this will support back to API 7. As I said, it could be a mismatch of classes which is causing your problem. Sorry, but I've got to sign off for the night.

Answer (score 12):

Make your `MainActivity` extend `ActionBarActivity` instead of `FragmentActivity`.

`ActionBarActivity` itself extends `FragmentActivity` so you should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Fragment Documents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setHasOptionsMenu(boolean))

> public void setHasOptionsMenu (boolean hasMenu) Report that this fragment would like to participate in populating the options menu by receiving a call to onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu, MenuInflater) and related methods.

Hence you should call `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` in your `onCreate()`.

Or for backwards compatibility it's better to place this call as late as possible at the end of `onCreate()` or even later in `onActivityCreated()`.Try using this in either `onCreate()` or `onActivityCreated()`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I can't use setHasOptionsMenu(true) inside my onCreate() any ideas why? maybe because it's a FragmentActivity and not a normal Fragment?